# Pentaho Data integration how to move transformation from one server to another

Tags: pentaho, pdi

What's the best practice of migrating pentaho job/transformations from one server to another?

We've set up DEV, QA, UAT, Production PDI server with carte running on AWS. And developers in our team are using community edition to program and test locally with local carte service.

The servers are using database repository and local pcs are using file based repository. 
Typically, when we migrate a transformation we will have to export xml and find those xml piece for that transformation/job and import into target servers.

I don't think this is a good practice, considering we are moving on CI/CD along with other java/js code.

Please advice a better way to do migration.

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is less about migrating from one server to another, and more about migrating from one repository type to another.  Do you have a compelling reason to use different repository types?

We use file-based repositories for all environments, and a directory synchronization tool for migrations.  We went with file-based repositories so our source control system could be used with it.